# redirect static files to nginx using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, nginx

I'm running nginx for static files(images, scripts) on 81 port and apache with php on 80.
Is it possible to redirect with .htaccess all iamges, styles, scripts requests to the same url but 81 instaed of 80 port?

I'm not very familiar with mod_rewrite

something like 
    if mysite.com/path/file.xxx has extension jpg or png or css
    then redirect to  mysite.com:81/path/file.xxx

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would do it the other away around: have Nginx proxy anything that's not a static file to a backend Apache. Having Apache look at all the incoming requests would defeat the purpose, since you use Nginx to avoid the inefficiencies of Apache when handling numerous requests. http://kbeezie.com/view/apache-with-nginx/ is a reasonable guide to the setup.

Comment: I concur. With the method you're using (least at the time of asking this question) you would still have the same fundamental problem. With Nginx in front of Apache you take a lot of load off the Apache server. mod_rewrite and simply handling calls to static resources takes quite a bit more resources then letting nginx do it. Just be sure to check what version of Nginx you are using as many distro provided copies are still using the old 0.7.67 when the current stable is 1.0.10 and supports nifty features like try_files (i.e.: try_files $uri $uri/ @apache;)